# Django AuthenticationForm - user does not get logged in

Tags: django

I have a login form like so:

login_form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

  <h2>Login</h2>

  <form action="/accounts/login/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />

  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

A login complete page like so:

login_complete.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}You are logged in{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

    <h2>Thank you for logging in</h2>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>foo</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Login view:

```
def login(request):        
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        auth.login(request, form.get_user())
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/login/complete")
else:
    form = AuthenticationForm()
token = {}
token.update(csrf(request))
token["form"] = form
return render_to_response("registration/login_form.html", token)
```

However the user does not get logged in. Username and password are correct (I tried with invalid combinations and I stay on the login page in that case and it displays an error) and I am using the correct login() method (auth.login and not my login() by accident).

Edit: My login() method is being called, it also shows me the login complete page correctly, but the

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>foo</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Edit2:
Changing 
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
to

```
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

does not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are not passing user object to template, try `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`

Comment: Hello, thanks, that seems like it should work, but it does not.

Comment: Note that Django comes with [authentication views and forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). You should use the built in login view and form if possible, rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `render` instead of `render_to_response`. The `render_to_response` method is obsolete.

If you use `render`, you don't need to do anything in the view to handle the csrf token, and you will be able to access any variables set by context processors like `request` and `user`.

```
def login(request):        
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            auth.login(request, form.get_user())
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/login/complete")
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "registration/login_form.html", form)
```

You also need to update any other views that use `render_to_response`, like login complete.